# How to select specific processes with 'top'?

Tags: shell, text-processing, top

In case of one program having multiple instances, running `pidof program` gives:

```
`1 2 3`
```

`top -p` accepts comma-delimited arguments: `1, 2, 3`.

This means that `` top -p `pidof program` `` won't work:

```
    top: unknown argument '1'
usage:  top -hv | -bcisSH -d delay -n iterations [-u user | -U user] -p pid [,pid ...]
```

Can you show me how to do this. I'm not familiar with awk, sed, etc...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An alternative to `sed` for simple things like this is `tr`:

```
top -p $(pidof program | tr ' ' ',')
```

`tr` can also easily handle a variable number of spaces:

```
tr -s ' ' ','
```

Additionally, if you have it available, `pgrep` can work well here:

```
top -p $(pgrep -d , program)
```

Make sure that you leave a space between `-d` and `,` as the comma is the argument (the deliminator).

Also, note that pgrep will return every result of "program" so if you have a process called "program-foo," then this will also be returned (hence the name pgrep).

Comment: For more than one program `top -p $(pgrep -d, "(nginx|mysql)" )`

Answer (score 6):

`sed` replaces your  with `,`:

```
top -p $(pidof program | sed 's/ /, /g')
```

Answer (score 3):

This works nicely for keeping an eye on more than one program:

```
top -p `pgrep -d, -f program1`, `pgrep -d, -f program2`
```

Comment: Better use: `top -p $(pgrep -d, "(nginx|mysql)" )`

Comment: What if you want to distinguish between say `ssh` and `ssh -x`?